# How to compare string to String Array in C#?

Tags: c#, compare, user-agent, string-comparison

I have an string;

```
String uA = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12D508 Twitter for iPhone";

String[] a= {"iphone","ipad","ipod"};
```

It must return `ipad` because ipad is in the first match ipad at the string.
In other case

```
String uA = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone/iPad; CPU OS 8_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12D508";
```

Same string array first match to `iPhone`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you want the word within the array which occurs earliest in the target string? That sounds like you might want something like:

```
return array.Select(word => new { word, index = target.IndexOf(word) })
            .Where(pair => pair.index != -1)
            .OrderBy(pair => pair.index)
            .Select(pair => pair.word)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Those steps in detail:

- Project the words into a sequence of word/index pairs, where the index is the index of that word within the target string
- Omit words that didn't occur in the target string by removing pairs where the index is -1 (`string.IndexOf` returns -1 if it's not found)
- Order by index to make the earliest word occur as the first pair
- Select the word within each pair, as we no longer care about indexes
- Return the first word, or `null` if the sequence is empty

Comment: Better answer, it consider the `null` case

Comment: Wouldn't a regex that matches and captures any of the words be faster? The group with the lowest index would then be the winner

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I wouldn't like to guess whether it would be faster. I suspect it would be harder to understand though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 String uA = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12D508 Twitter for iPhone";

 String[] a = { "iphone", "ipad", "ipod" };

 var result = a.Select(i => new { item = i, index = uA.IndexOf(i) })
               .Where(i=>i.index >= 0)
               .OrderBy(i=>i.index)
               .First()
               .item;
```

Comment: I think this may trigger a NullReferenceException on "First", doesn't it? And the where shouldn't be a ">="?

Comment: If it's the first word in the string, it would be 0. So as Jon Skeet posted, you would need the index != -1 to verify that it was contained in the string.

Comment: @MVCDS I'm going to change to ">="

Answer (score 1):

here is a none linq method to do that,

```
    static string GetFirstMatch(String uA, String[] a)
    {
        int startMatchIndex = -1;
        string firstMatch = "";
        foreach (string s in a)
        {
            int index = uA.ToLower().IndexOf(s.ToLower());
            if (index == -1)
                continue;
            else if (startMatchIndex == -1)
            {
                startMatchIndex = index;
                firstMatch = s;
            }
            else if (startMatchIndex > index)
            {
                startMatchIndex = index;
                firstMatch = s;
            }
        }
        return firstMatch;
    }
```